# backbonejs: can I make one view superior than another view?

Tags: css, backbone.js

I have a question about backbonejs viewing.

So, the scenario is like this. I have created a dialog view which turn full page to gray and there is a dialog box in the center which show some content, something like this

> http://www.alessioatzeni.com/wp-content/tutorials/jquery/login-box-modal-dialog-window/index.html

Then I am creating a loading box view, something I find like this:

> http://cssload.net/

However, the gray full page OVERLAY my loading box view. That is, I cannot really see my loading box because the dialog view "cover" my loading box view. How can I solve this problem? Like can I prioritize the views in backbonejs so that loading box view is always surperior than dialog view?

Thanks~

Comment: Sounds like a job for CSS: check out `z-index`

Comment: Is your dialog box a new view? You could put the loading in this view and display it when you want.

Comment: @WillM I would not go for `z-index` in this case

Comment: Cool!. This can be done simply by z-index and I don't have to touch any backbonejs stuff. Thanks!